# Changed checkbox state when select is changed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, select, checkbox

I have a form and I'd like to make it so when the select box is changed, it's respective checkbox is checked automatically.

Could anyone shed any light on this? Let's say for the purpose the select boxes are 'select1, select2 etc..' and the checkboxes are 'checkbox1, checkbox2 etc..'

[image: Screenshot of form]

Snippet of table (first row)

```html
<table width="820" class="content">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Issue?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Beret</td>
            <td><select name="select_beret">
                <option value="8405-99-1278122">8405-99-1278122 : 48cm - 2 in stock</option><option value="8405-99-1278124">8405-99-1278124 : 50cm - 3 in stock</option><option value="8405-99-1278125">8405-99-1278125 : 51cm - 1 in stock</option></select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" name ="qty_beret"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_beret" value="Y"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you not write an example for us to work with? Could you also show your attempts of doing this and explain what you think the problem is with your attempt? Thanks.

Comment: @NewToJS I don't have an example of my attempts because I haven't got a clue where to start. The only thing I can post is the source code of the table with the form elements

Comment: I could give you a working demo of what you're asking but since you have an item pre-selected. This will mean the client will have to select a different item before selecting the pre-set item before the checkbox is checked. You are aware of this?

Comment: I didn't even think of this, I'll change the default value to prevent this, silly me! @NewToJS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example of having one function run all change events for your select boxes. (if/when) you update your question with your new source code and display comments to explain each step.

```js
window.onload=function(){
var Selects=document.getElementsByClassName('Items');
for(var i=0; i<Selects.length; i++){
 Selects[i].addEventListener('change',function(){
  var Cbox=false;
  if(this.value!==""){
  Cbox=true;
  }
  document.getElementById('issue_'+this.id).checked=Cbox;
 },false);
}
}
```

```html
Beret 
<select class="Items" id="beret" name="select_beret">
<option value="">Beret Sizes</option>
<option value="8405-99-9685843">Item 1</option>
<option value="8405-99-1847365">Item 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="issue_beret" value=""/><br>
Jumper
<select class="Items" id="jumper" name="select_jumper">
<option value="">Jumper Sizes</option>
<option value="8405-99-1717171">Item 1</option>
<option value="8405-99-3939393">Item 2</option>
</select>
<input type="checkbox" id="issue_jumper" value=""/><br>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense now I've seen it, and it works opposed to my method of a function for each item. Thanks!

Comment: Very welcome, if you don't understand any of the source code please let me know and I will be more than happy to put comments in place.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a little trial and error, it wasn't as hard as I first thought and maybe I was just being lazy.

Simple javascript to select the checkbox then call the function using an onChange event on the select box.

Only downside is there has to be a function for each checkbox, however, it does work!

Comment: If you update your question with your new source code I will see if I can change a few things so it only requires one function to run all select events. I will post a quick demo.

Answer (score 0):

I gave you 2 options, please read the JavaScript comment:

```js
// If you wanted to just toggle the checkox on, as soon
// as someone changes the value of the select box...
$( '.content' ).on( 'change', 'select', function (e) {
  var $this     = $( this ), // the select menu
      $row      = $this.parents( 'tr:first' ),
      $checkbox = $row.find( 'input[type=checkbox]' );
  
  $checkbox.prop( 'checked', true );
});

// If you wanted to toggle the checkbox on and off
// based on the user selecting something from the 
// select box (like default vs actual value)
$( '.content' ).on( 'change', 'select', function (e) {
  var $this     = $( this ), // the select menu
      $row      = $this.parents( 'tr:first' ),
      $checkbox = $row.find( 'input[type=checkbox]' );
  
  $checkbox.prop( 'checked', $this.val() !== 'no-value' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table width="820" class="content">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Issue?</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Beret</td>
      <td>
        <select name="select_beret">
          <option value="no-value">Please select something</option>
          <option value="8405-99-1278122">8405-99-1278122 : 48cm - 2 in stock</option>
          <option value="8405-99-1278124">8405-99-1278124 : 50cm - 3 in stock</option>
          <option value="8405-99-1278125">8405-99-1278125 : 51cm - 1 in stock</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="qty_beret"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_beret" value="Y"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```